# Individual directory options for every VirtualHost in Apache2

Tags: apache2, authentication, virtualhost

I have a Debian 9 server with two static IPv4 addresses. One of them is public and the other one is in the server's VPN subnet (the machine is running an OpenVPN server).

There is a DNS server in the VPN subnet that handles internal name resolution with an own TLD. So both of these IPs have a domain name associated to them (let's call them `public.domain` and `private.domain`).

My Apache2 server has two VirtualHosts, one for each domain. There is a non-indexed subdirectory inside the document root that contains private data. What I want to do is password-protect this subdirectory when called from the public, but not require any authentication when accessed over the VPN address.

This is my public VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost public.domain:443>

    [...]

    <Directory /path/to/private/directory>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Private Data"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my private VirtualHost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost private.domain:443>

    [...]

    <Directory /path/to/private/directory>
        AuthType None
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

As it turns out, this configuration is not working properly:

- When I call the protected directory over `public.domain`, everything still works fine and I can authenticate normally.
- When I call it from `private.domain` I don't get asked for login credentials (which *is* what I wanted), but get a `HTTP 403 Forbidden` response (Which is obviously *not* what I wanted).

It seems like the `<Directory>` options in the two config files are interfering with each other. What am I doing wrong here? Or is this possible at all?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: At first blush, I would think Apache would read just the first or last directory directive, however, wrapping them in different virtual hosts is a new twist. I am not sure if what you want can be done this way. It may be you need to use another method, one wrapped in PHP. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution on my own.

I created two symlinks, both pointing to the desired folder. Then, I used one of them for the public VirtualHost and the other one for the private one. Works perfectly fine, just make sure to add `Options FollowSymLinks` in the `<Directory>` directives.

Comment: Funny! I thought about symlinks then said Naaahhhhh... that won't work! I guess I should have spoken up anyway. Sorry. Thanks for sharing a solution. Cheers!!

Comment: To be honest, I didn't think it was going to work either. I probably just tried it because my main PC runs Windows - the OS where the most stupid solutions you could possibly think of turn out to work best ;)

Comment: Freaking Windows! Sometimes you have to run it, but I prefer Linux. I used to maintain windows years ago. It was okay. Just hacky and sometimes the simplest thing they make complicated. Cheers mate!!

Comment: I would have switches to Linux entirely many years ago if the major games and stuff like Adobe Creative Cloud were supported, just because I find it way more convenient. But that's an entirely different story and would require an own discussion. Cheers! ;)